# send ajax post after delay

Tags: jquery, ajax, events, keypress

I have a input field, where the user can be type a search string.
This string should be send as an ajax post on keydown event:

```
$( "#inputField" ).keypress(function() {  
  // AJAX
});
```

With this function, the ajax post will send every keypress.
For Example: The user wrote "Example" => 7 letters => 7 time ajax post

How can I make it better?

Comment: You need to `debounce` your inputs, there's plenty of existing solutions; once you know the terminology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this small function, it works in such a way that it runs after the user finishes typing and delays

Sample code:

```
function debounce(callback, ms) {
  var timer = 0;
  return function() {
    var context = this, args = arguments;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
      callback.apply(context, args);
    }, ms || 0);
  };
}
// Sample:
$('#input').keyup(debounce(function (e) {
  console.log('Time Ended!', this.value);
}, 800));
```

Try it:

```js
function debounce(callback, ms) {
  var timer = 0;
  return function() {
    var context = this, args = arguments;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
      callback.apply(context, args);
    }, ms || 0);
  };
}
// Sample:
$('#input').keyup(debounce(function (e) {
  console.log('Time Ended!', this.value);
}, 800));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="input">Search:
<input id="input" type="text" placeholder="words..."/>
</label>
```